# Plesk command script php

Tags: php, plesk

I have a script php that creates a subdomain with plesk, when I execute this one with the term, it works well, my subdomain is created and no error appears. But my problem is when I submit my Html form I have a first script that call my "plesk script" by

```
system("php plesk.php");
```

but the script does nothing, my subdomain is not creating.
My safe_mode php is turned off, so I ask if someone knows something about it, please help me.

thank you guys !

Comment: Are you sure you're in the correct directory? Does the script execute at all? If you enable error reporting, do you get any errors/warnings/notes?

Comment: Yes my script is executed because I print the result of the system command, and I have an echo line in my plesk script that is well printed.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you use the Linux `$PATH` variable to find the php command. But if you are running the php command from your php system function its possible that the `$PATH` isn't set. So you have to define the complete path to the php executable.

```
system("/usr/bin/php /complete/path/plesk.php");
```

And you need enough rights for the file to execute it.

Comment: The file is called, but the commands aren't executed again, I don't understand why they are not

Comment: Perhaps you have the same path problems in your plesk.php?

Comment: I've verified my path and every path is good so I don't understand what you mean !